# Unable to get correct disk data during cloning from template using Terraform Vsphere provider

Tags: terraform, vmware, vsphere

I have a template on vSphere with 8 disks yet when I try to clone from the template through Terraform, it is only able to view 2 disks.

It works for the first 2 disks -

```
  disk {
    label            = "disk0"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks[0].size
  }

  disk {
    label            = "disk1"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks[1].size
    unit_number      = 1
  }
```

But as soon as I enter the third disk, like this -

```
  disk {
    label            = "disk2"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.[2].size
    unit_number      = 2
  }
```

, it gives me an error -

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 82, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm":
  82:     size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.2.size
    |----------------
    | data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks is list of object with 2 elements

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

If I were to remove this third disk(label disk2) and change the disk sizes of the first 2 disks(only increase since that's what is allowed), I would see the changes correctly. But as soon as I enter the third disk(label disk2) with some predefined size and run the build, it creates a new disk which is definitely not what I want.

I suspect this is because my first 2 disks are on the first SCSI controller, and my other disks are on other SCSI controllers, and Terraform is considering only the first one by default.

Edit:

This is how the template data looks like -

```
variable "vsphere_source_template_name" {
  default = "dev-dummy-template"
}

data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = var.vsphere_source_template_name
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase your `scsi_controller_scan_count` in your vm template data source. By default it will only scan 1 (the first) scsi controller, but if you specify the number in the vm you are trying to clone from, the additional disks should be available in the data source.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/data-sources/virtual_machine#scsi_controller_scan_count

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this is a syntax issue

For disk[1]
size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks[1].size

For disk[2] you entered the following. there is an additional dot
size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.[2].size